# Xcode 4 and C++ highlight compiler errors directly in the code

Tags: c++, xcode4, cinder

I started to play around with [libcinder](http://libcinder.org/) and do so using *Xcode 4*.

When compiling, Xcode 4 puts compiler errors in the left bar. 

However, when I click them, Xcode does not highlight them in the code. Worse it doesn't even show the line number to which the error belongs!

So I have to check the whole compile log in order to figure out what is wrong. I think this problem is related to the projects files cinder generates, because it works when I create a new C++ project in Xcode.

Comment: Just saw that it works for some errors but not for all?? Can I tell Xcode that it should also display the line numbers along with the error message?